# Using spring-form tags to insert/update entity with non-primitive attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

In my spring application, the forms for insert/update a entity in the database have a structure similar to this:

```
<jsp:include page="../../common/cadastrar.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="entity" value="Usuario"/>

    <jsp:param name="arguments" value="login"/>
    <jsp:param name="arguments" value="senha"/>
    <jsp:param name="arguments" value="first_name"/>
    <jsp:param name="arguments" value="last_name"/>
    <jsp:param name="arguments" value="email"/>
</jsp:include>
```

which redirect to this shared jsp page (common to all the views):

```
<c:url value="${param.entity}/cadastra" var="cadastra"/>
<form:form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="${cadastra}">

    <table>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${paramValues.arguments}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${item == 'senha'}">
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="${item}">${item}</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="${item}" type="password"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="${item}">${item}</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="${item}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>
```

When my entity class have only primitive attributes (Integer, String, etc), this code works fine. But I can't figure out how to do the same for classes like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
public class Cliente extends Entidade {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_usuario")
    private Usuario usuario;

    @Column(name="documento")
    private String documento;

    @Column(name="cpf")
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name="cnpj")
    private String cnpj;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="endereco_entrega", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_cliente")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_endereco")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Endereco> endereco;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="pedido_cliente", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_cliente")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_pedido")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Pedido> pedido;
}
```

where some of the attributes are other entities. Anyone can point me a direction to do this?

**UPDATE 1**

Usuario.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario extends Entidade {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "senha")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="role_members", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_user")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_role")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Role> Autorizacao = new ArrayList<Role>();
}
```

Endereco.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="endereco")
public class Endereco {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="logadouro")
    private String logradouro;

    @Column(name="numero")
    private String numero;

    @Column(name="complemento")
    private String complemento;

    @Column(name="bairro")
    private String bairro;

    @Column(name="cidade")
    private String cidade;

    @Column(name="estado")
    private String estado;

    @Column(name="cep")
    private String cep;
}
```

Pedido.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pedido")
public class Pedido {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="produtos_do_pedido", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_pedido")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_produto")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Produto> produto;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="cobranca_do_pedido", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_pedido")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_cobranca")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Cobranca> cobranca;
}
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of what those entities are, I cannot say anything. The way of handling that highly depends on entities structure. You may have : direct string <-> entity conversion (Date), checkboxes (enums or options), multiple fields for one attribute (complex entity), etc.

Comment: Ok, I updata the question to include the entities related to `Cliente`.